# hadoop fs -get not working in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, get

I have created single node hadoop cluster in Ubuntu .

I was trying to copy file from hdfs to local fs but when i issued command

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop fs -get /user/hduser/Employee /home/output/
```

I got a message

```
get: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to add the exact command you are using?

Comment: @ashwini dear please post your full command so that we can guess the problem.

Comment: @ashwini to copy HDFS file to local machine you can use, -copyFromLocal; and you have mentioned a directory not a file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general format for hadoop shell command **get** shown below,

```
hadoop fs -get <HDFS File> <local File Directory>
```

You have used as, `hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop fs -get /user/hduser/Employee /home/output/` in here `/user/hduser/Employee` is an directory not a file.

you should do as,

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop fs -get /user/hduser/Employee[/FILENAME] /home/output/
```

Else If you want to copy a directory(*i.e folder*) you can use `dfs -copyToLocal`,

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop dfs -copyToLocal /user/hduser/Employee /home/output/
```

You can find Hadoop Shell Commands [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html).

Comment: It also appears that the OP has the paths permuted. I suspect that /home/output is a path in HDFS holding the results of a job and /home/hduser is the home directory on the local file system of the hadoop user. In that case the paths should be permuted

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that /user/hduser is a directory and not a file.I once had this problem and I tried hadoop fs -ls which showed
-rwx r-x -r-x

A directory would be drwx r-x r-x .
If this is the problem you need to remove it using -rmr /user/hduser and make it again with -mkdir.

Other options,try -copyToLocal or try downloading the file from HDFS webportal i.e. namenode_IP:50070